# Get Messages Beta app to run on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, messages, beta

I wanted to use iMessage/Messages on my 2008 MacBook. I am stuck on Lion. I saw the Messages beta, and installed it. However, it appears Apple disabled it after Mountain Lion was released.

I really want to be able to get this to work.

Is there *any* way to get this to work? I can try messing with the package contents if I need to, I've dabbled (futilely) with it trying to change the plist contents to accept lower OS X versions. So I'm up for that. I would need instructions, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to get the mountain lion installed even if the 2008 MacBook officially would not support it. There are number of procedures and tools available, start perhaps on [MacRumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/summary-install-mountain-lion-on-unsupported-mac-working-as-of-2-2017.2031759/) that has the most up to date instructions.

Here an image of a 2007 MacBook running macOS 10.8

[image: MacBook 2007]

Comment: I ended up finally getting Mountain Lion installed ;)